# SSIS package for export data into csv file to FTP

Tags: ssis

I'm creating SSIS package for to get .csv file to my local server and transfer it to FTP
When I get my csv into FTP and open into excel, My data getting shift over to other columns. Is there internally any kind set up do I need to change? 
Also I tried different text qualifier still did not work.

Comment: Inspect the CSV file in a text editor, maybe there are some unexpected commas. Do ALL rows get shifted over or just some?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there may be hidden characters in your data set. If you are using comma's you may want to consider using a lesser used character for the delimiter such as a pipe "|". For instance an address may naturally have comma's. If a pipe shows up in an address field it's probably a type-o, and is far less likely. Things that shift data cells are often things like tab characters and CRLF. You can also open your data set in a text editor like notepad ++ and choose the "Show all Characters" option under "View->Show Symbols" menu option to see what the exact character is. If it's rampant in your data set you can use the replace function within the Derived Column Task to scrub the data as it comes out of the data source.